# Use a variable to change UIButton image

Tags: ios, swift, uibutton

I want to change a `UIButton` image using a variable that contains the name of the image.
The variable name is `cardSeaTapped` and contain "ruterEss".

I think of something like this (I know this is wrong):

```
btnCardSea1.setImage(UIImage(cardSeaTapped, ofType: "png"), for: .normal)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may need

```
btnCardSea1.setImage(UIImage(named:"\(cardSeaTapped).png"), for: .normal)
```

or

```
btnCardSea1.setImage(UIImage(named:cardSeaTapped), for: .normal)
```

where `cardSeaTapped` is of **String** type

Comment: Yes, cardSeaTapped is of String type.
When i use:
    `btnCardSea1.setImage(UIImage(named:"\(cardSeaTapped).png"), for: .normal)`
the default image get erased and the button get invisible. Like the filename is wrong.

Comment: sure image exists and membership is checked

Comment: I want to change the image when a tapped the button. And when I tapped the button it get invisible.
Yes the image exists.

Comment: select the image from project navigator then from file inspector tap make sure **target membership** is ticked

Comment: Yes target membership is ticked.

Comment: @user3266053 if the image showed in other answer then it should show when use my code where the image can be dynamic , check carfeully the name of the image

Answer (score 0):

You can use image literal
You have to drag and drop your image into assets and then in setImage method you have to write image literal and then a image logo will appear and when you double tap on it then you will get all your images and then you have to choose one no need to write the image name in your code.
when you comment your code then it will looks like 
//btnCardSea1.setImage(#imageLiteral(resourceName: "cardSeaTapped"), for: .normal)

[plz check image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/R5YaY.png)

Comment: This also would work but should be **btnCardSea1.setImage(#imageLiteral(resourceName: "ruterEss"), for: .normal)**

Comment: Yeah that's  image name.... it was type mistake btnCardSea1.setImage(#imageLiteral(resourceName: "cardSeaTapped"), for: .normal)  and it should be  btnCardSea1.setImage(#imageLiteral(resourceName: "ruterEss"), for: .normal).    ......but image literal is very helpful it shorts your code

Comment: I am to tired. I want to use the cardSeaTapped variabel, because it is changing. If I use #imageLiteral "ruterEss" it will always show "ruterEss".

Comment: then make a variable and assign a image to that variable by image literal or by uinamed and your setImage looks like btnCardSea1.setImage(imageVariable, for: .normal)    and you can change the imageVariable value which is your desired image at any event